# The morphism of rings inducing the diagonal morphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to see that the diagonal morphism for affine schemes $\Delta: Spec(R) \rightarrow Spec(R \otimes R)$ is induced by the morphism of rings $R \otimes R \rightarrow R$, $r \otimes r' \rightarrow r \cdot r'$?

I know this is elementary, but I'm stuck and even don't see this for the induced map on the topological spaces.

Comment: How have you had the diagonal morphism defined?

Comment: Using the universal property of the fibered product $Spec(R) \times Spec(R) = Spec (R \otimes R)$, it is the map induced by the identity maps $Spec (R) \rightarrow Spec (R)$.

Comment: Well, the ring morphism $R \otimes R \to R$ you describe is defined by the dual universal property.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Could you explain that? I'm not familiar enough with category theory to see that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be begin with, let's recall how, if $R$ is a ring of functions on a space $X$, then $R\otimes R$ becomes a ring of functions on $X \times X$.  Namely,
if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions on $X$, then $f\otimes g$ gets mapped
to the function $(x,y) \mapsto f(x)g(y)$.

Okay, now lets restrict this function to the diagonal.  We then get the function
$$x \mapsto (x,x) \mapsto f(x)g(x) = (fg)(x).$$

Composing these two, we see that if we map $f\otimes g$ to a function on $X\times X$, and then restrict to the diagonal, we obtain the product function $fg$.  This answers your question.